# Reveal a fixed section on scroll from bottom/behind of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a section (could be bigger than the viewport height) revealing from bottom on scroll like this website http://actualidea.com.

I know something like this can be done with footer position fixed (like the snippet) but I want something similar to the example website [link](http://actualidea.com/) so that I can use that section anywhere in the page.

Any jQuery ideas are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

```
footer {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That scroll effect is actually another page that is moved to on scroll. Look in the URL - it says `actualidea.com/harrys` when you are in the orange text.

Answer (score 0):

An effect like the one on http://actualidea.com/ would require the use of a couple of JavaScript libraries along with CSS. I would suggest looking at  scrollrevealJS - https://scrollrevealjs.org/, and rellax (Parallax library) - https://dixonandmoe.com/rellax/

Answer (score 0):

Digging around, I think he used Readymag. https://readymag.com It essentially does scrolling with JavaScript by moving the a container's `top` css property. Looks pretty complicated, I think there's a lot of edge-cases to consider. They register events for all sorts of scroll behavior including the keyboard.